# Task.Run how to write it with action and ref variable name

Tags: c#, syntax, task-parallel-library, task

I am standing for a "little" syntax problem and cannt figure out how to correctly write what I desire.

I have the following method:

```
public void DoSomeMagic(string foo, ref string bar)
{
    //DoSomeMagic...
}
```

Now I would like to offload this code inside a Task.Run I would normally write the following:

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    string foo = "Hello Foo";
    string bar = "Hello Bar";

    await Task.Run(() => DoSomeMagic(foo, ref bar));
}
```

This doesn't compile telling me: "Cannot use 'ref' or 'out' parameter 'bar' inside an anonymous method body"

So I thought why even do the () => since I am just calling the method and I could reduce it to this:

```
Task.Run(DoSomeMagic(foo, ref bar));
```

This again doesn't compile telling me: Cannot resolve method 'Run(void)', candidates are: Run(Action) and Run(Func)

So again no problem Visual Studio your demand is my command.

And changed the code to this:

```
Task.Run((Action)DoSomeMagic(foo, ref bar));
```

Again doesn't compile telling me: Cannot cast expression of type 'void' to type 'Action',

Okay this starts getting tricky...

I than tried to instead of returning void I will just try int and cast to Func
giving me the error: Cannot cast expression of type 'int' to type 'Func'

Saw that one coming but I thought lets give it a try:

So I tried the following approach:

```
public Action CallDoSomeMagic(string foo, ref string bar)
{
    //DoSomeMagic...
    return new Action(() => DoSomeMagic(foo, ref bar));
}

Task.Run(CallDoSomeMagic);
```

But this again gives me the message "Cannot use 'ref' or 'out' parameter 'bar' inside an anonymous method body"

Since my headache is increasing with every try, I thought you guys can help me out.
Is it even possible?

Comment: Read the error message: "Cannot use 'ref' or 'out' parameter 'bar' inside an anonymous method body" - `bar` is a "ref parameter". You can't use it inside the lambda. So... don't!

Comment: @MarcGravell Its tricky since I want to use ref, are you telling me its not possible?

Comment: It is not possible, for 2 reasons - I will add an answer...

Comment: Your first example compiles here.

Comment: @PatrickHofman do you mean the example with just `//DoSomeMagic` ?

Comment: @PatrickHofman k; that compiling isn't a surprise then...

Comment: @PatrickHofman a compiler error is only mentioned after the second example

Comment: @MarcGravell: after second code block: Cannot use 'ref' or 'out' parameter 'bar' inside an anonymous method body

Comment: Not sure if i should put this as an answer, but i doubt you will ever see this work. Since you can manipulate control flow with async await you would be able to create totally bogus logic manipulating your parameters throughout your process inbetween sections you are awaiting for. Pretty sure that's why they aren't allowing it

Comment: @AndreasMüller nah, that's not really the reason - this limitation pre-dates things like `async` - and indeed, what you describe is always the case in a multi-threaded world.

Comment: @MarcGravell Interesting answer indeed. I can imagine them finding a way around it, but when i ran into this issue and thought about it i was glad that the compiler doesn't allow it, even though in some cases it would be nice. Usually it's happening when you should consider refactoring your code a little, so i'm ok with that

Comment: @AndreasMüller indeed; the simplest "fix" here is: instead of passing a `ref string`, to pass a reference to an object of `SomeTypeThatHasAStringProperty` - then just access `obj.Bar` or whatever: done (edited that into my answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the message says: you can't do that.

You could take a **copy** of the parameter value, and capture *that*, for example:

```
public Action CallDoSomeMagic(string foo, ref string bar)
{
    var snapshot = bar;
    return new Action(() => DoSomeMagic(foo, ref snapshot));
}
```

But note that updates to `snapshot` are not visible outside the caller via `bar`.

The reasons for this are two-fold:

Firstly, captured variables used on a lambda become fields on a compiler-generated context class. This works fine for non-ref/out parameters, as they already have a copy semantic. So in the case of my `snapshot` example, this is actually:

```
var ctx = new CompilerGeneratedContextClassWithHorribleName();
ctx.foo = foo;
ctx.snapshot = bar;
return new Action(ctx.CompilerGeneratedMethod);
```

where `CompilerGeneratedMethod` is:

```
DoSomeMagic(foo, ref snapshot);
```

this isn't possible for refs, as you'd essentially need the field to be a reference to a string-reference, which is... messy.

But more importantly: consider the lifetime of the caller. This could be:

```
void SomeMethod() {
    string s = "abc";
    CallDoSomeMagic("def", ref s);
}
```

Note in particular that the code needs to work even if the delegate is invoked much later - as indeed we might expect it to in your case since it involves `Task` and `async`. Now: if `SomeMethod` has exited: ***where is that reference to a string-reference pointing?*** Hint: it is just an arbitrary location on the stack, now out of scope.

---

Just to give a simpler workaround: instead of passing `ref string bar`, consider passing `SomeType obj`, where `obj.Bar` is the `string` you want; i.e.

```
public Action CallDoSomeMagic(string foo, SomeType obj)
{
    return new Action(() => DoSomeMagic(foo, obj));
}

public void DoSomeMagic(string foo, SomeType obj)
{
    // read and write obj.Bar here
}
```

Note you could also move `foo` to `obj.Foo` if you wanted.